# How to use apachectl with systemd instances

Tags: systemd, rhel, apache-httpd

I’m attempting to isolate sites and configurations using multiple instances of httpd via systemd as per this [article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5062121). Everything seems to be working as expected, however when attempting to debug issues in the instances via apachectl -S or apachectl -M, only the main instance appears to be known. I’ve attempted to pass the -f flag and the path of the appropriate instance specific configuration file, however I get errors because the variables in systemd are only valid in the systemd unit file execution.

Any help on how to use apachectl or a viable alternative would be appreciated.